# Decimal to binary transformation does not work for some conditions

Tags: c

Input:

```
    Enter a decimal number: 12
```

Output:

```
    The binary number is : 1100
```

I ought tried this way->

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

int input=get_input();
long long complete_integer=binary_conversion(input);
reverse_digits(complete_integer);
}
int get_input() {
int number = 0;
printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
scanf("%d",&number);
return number;
}
int binary_conversion(int number,int value) {
long long complete_integer = 0;
int base=2;

while (number != 0) {
//Take the last digit from the integer and push the digit back of complete integer
complete_integer = complete_integer * 10 + number%base;
number /= base;
}
printf("Completed integer number : %d\n",complete_integer);
return complete_integer;
}

int reverse_digits(long long complete_integer) {
    int binary = complete_integer;
    int last_digit = 0;

    while(binary != 0) {

        last_digit = last_digit * 10 + binary % 10;
        binary /= 10;
    }
    printf("The binary number is: %d",last_digit);
}
```

I am almost close to the solution. But my system does not work for all the conditions like
If I give input like

```
Enter a decimal number: 12
```

It gives the output from my code like

```
Binary numbers are: 11
```

So, Here is the problem. Where I made the wrong?. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's kind of odd seeing `% 10` in a *binary* method. Shouldn't that be `% 2` and `/= 2`?

Comment: It's also worth noting this prints the digits in reverse order.

Comment: I update the function naming for more clarifications

Comment: This is the point where you step through it in a debugger to unravel the mystery.

Comment: Would you propose an answer?

Comment: Proposal: Please use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: Ok, I am trying

Comment: It's worth testing these functions independently. Right now you are only able to test them together, and the bug could be in either. Try each in isolation and verify they both work independently before integrating them together.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say `complete_integer = complete_integer * 10 + number%base;` is way off base.

Comment: Implicit declaration of `binary_conversion` incompatible to definition below (1 parameter/2 parameters) - UB.

Comment: Really not a good idea to create a weird numbers like `complete_integer` and `last_digit` just to make a `printf`'s `%d` (decimal) - compatible "binary" representation. Remember that `input` is already binary in memory. What is `last_digit`? A number that's decimal representation is graphically the same that `input`'s binary representation. Its ineffective and has overflow risk since `complete_integer` much greater than `input`. Digits are not numbers but characters, save them to string and then reverse it, this is what should work for any base, not just base 2.

Comment: In case of base 2 a bit arythmetic could be used to print each `number`'s bit value left to right, this is more effective than division by 2, but requires `sizeof int` to get oldest bit. And bit shift could produce unexpected or undefined behavior in case of negative numbers, so `unsigned` should be used instead of `int`.